# NSIS Special Build - Logging and Long String (8192 byte)

Tags: nsis

I have found special builds of NSIS for Advanced Logging and Long strings (8192 bytes), but I need to incorporate both into an installer.

I do not have a developer environment set up where I could compile my own version of makensis, so I was hoping that somebody with this Advanced Logging and Long string configuration could share their makensis.exe and stubs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://www.mediafire.com/file/knsaqgs9dsaofba/nsis-2.46-ANSI-NSIS_CONFIG_LOG=yes%20NSIS_MAX_STRLEN=8192.zip) but I'm not sure what the log limit is, if you need to log strings > 2000 bytes you should file a bug report to get the logging fixed...