# Long String version of NSIS

Tags: nsis

We have been trying to compile long strings (>8192) to create a database update program (runs queries on the MSSQL database). The existing NSIS system (v2.5 or v3.0) cannot compile our strings. Previously, a special built of NSIS **([NSIS Special Build - Logging and Long String (8192 byte)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968357/nsis-special-build-logging-and-long-string-8192-byte))** was reported here, but is has compilation issues in login in. Anybody has a special built that can compile scripts with strings >8192?   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usual route to avoid similar issues is a creating helper script (js or vbs), move text processing here and call it as external like:

```
nsExec::ExecToStack 'cscript /NOLOGO //E:jscript script.js param1 param2...'
```

ExecToStack will execute script invisible from user and place result to stack.

Also, you can (but it more hard in implementation) write text processing using manual memory alloc with buffered binary input/output.

Comment: ...then with js/vbs scripting, you add the problems of parameter passing, text encoding, rights managements, security of data, difficulty of tracing / debugging... to the problems already addressed by your nsis script!

Comment: For every tool there is a area of responsibility and area of implementability. NSIS, BTW, is not designed for working with long strings as well and at all. If you have to do similar kind of work in installer, you SHOULD to think how to move around NSIS engine limitations. ANY solution will not be completely pure and will be compromised more or less.

Comment: There are several ways I see how to process long strings in NSIS:
1) Delegate text processing to tool that can do it well. I mean, using scripting (js or vbs).
2) Hardcode text processing into NSIS using API calls (System::Alloc, memset, str* or wcs* or MS-specific stuff). 
3) Write you own plugin
4) Recompile NSIS using long buffers for string, like topic starter asks.

Comment: Point by point:
1. is a common way. And I do not see stopping issues nor for security or technical implementation.
2. I want my enemy will debug and support this in hell.
3. Plugin - no bad solution, anyway, it is a little side project with own tricks and bugs.
4. Dirty hack. At least you will got unstable or not-working plugins.